# Get a couchbase Version with Java SDK

Tags: java, couchbase

Please i trying get a couchbase version with java 
for example with elasticsearch and java , I use this :
jmx.setValue("EsVersion", **org.elasticsearch.Version.CURRENT**.toString());

in the couchbase official client I don't have same instruction.
I find in all class and in repo official client and without success.

thx for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understood your question correctly, but you can get a version string for the SDK **`core-io` layer** you are using in the `CouchbaseEnvironment`, by calling the `packageNameAndVersion()` method:

```
String versionString = bucket.environment().packageNameAndVersion();
```

This will get you something like "`couchbase-jvm-core/1.2.5 (git: 1.2.5)`".
The top-level **`java-client` layer** should be 1 major version above, so here `2.2.5`.

Edit: in newer SDKs,  there are two additional methods on the `CouchbaseEnvironment`: `clientVersion()` gives the SDK version (which should be the most interesting) and `coreVersion()` gives the associated core-io artifact version.

Comment: this synchronization of minor.patch version numbers is likely to go away in a future version, but if that's the case, either the method will be reworked to include both version numbers (core and client layers) or a new method would be added to retrieve the client number (which is the layer most visible and most interesting to you)